# How to translate the menu navbar in core ui react?

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, core-ui

I am using the admin template for [react : coreui](https://coreui.io/pro/react/). To translate my labels in the component, I am using react-intl.

I would like to translate the navbar which is a simple array like that :

```
    export default {
  items: [
    {
        title: true,
        name: 'ESSAI DOM',
    },
    {
        name: 'Schools',
        url: '/schools',
        icon: 'fa fa-university'
    },
.... other items...
  ],  
};
```

My translations are in a json like that (example for 'french'):

```
{
    "Schools.Schools.title": "Ecoles"
}
```

In this example, I would like to write something like :

```
    {
     name : some_function(languageId, 'Schools.Schools.title'),
     .....
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution like that :

```
    export default {
  items: [
    {
        name : <FormattedMessage id="Navigation.home" defaultMessage="Home" />,
        url: '/',
        icon: 'fa fa-home'
    },
    {
        name : <FormattedMessage id="Navigation.schools" defaultMessage="Schools" />,
        url: '/schools',
        icon: 'fa fa-university'
    },
  ],  
};
```

I did not know we can manipulate React component outside a class.